# Nginx proxy_pass inconsistent behavior

Tags: docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx server that I'm using as the SSL-capable frontend for several back ends, which I understand is called a "reverse proxy."  For some time now, I've gotten very consistent results with a simple server block that basically says "If it's on this port, pass it to that container."  Then I added another container that I wanted behind the SSL frontend, and it's absolutely not working.  This is bizarre to me because I copied and pasted working blocks of code, changed the ports and container names, and the new block doesn't work.

Here's the details.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  frontend:
    image: djmcmath/mysite-frontend:v0.0.47b
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "433:433"
      - "8443:8443"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/:ro
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro
    networks: 
      - frontend
      - backend
      
  backend:
    image: djmcmath/mysite-backend:v0.0.15a
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - backend

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "db.mysite.com:3306"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: blog_user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: blog_pass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: blog_db
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/default-nonssl.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-nonssl.conf:ro
      - ./wordpress/docker-entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh:ro
      - ./wordpress/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 81:80
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - backend

networks: 
  frontend:
  backend:
```

Then the relevant bit from the nginx.conf:

```
#Blog
#Reverse proxy redirect; like the backend, where Cargo runs the service but can't do SSL, let Nginx do the SSL and wordpress just does wordpress.
server {
    listen 433 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:433 ssl http2;
    server_name mysite.com;
    
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
    add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' '4444' always;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect  off;
        proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass              http://wordpress:81/;
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;    
}
```

Then, obviously, a virtual host in the wordpress container listening on 80.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias www.mysite.com
  ServerAlias wordpress
</VirtualHost>
```

What I **expect** this to do is what it does for the container named "backend," which is:

- Nginx takes the connection on mysite.com:433 and redirects it to a container named "wordpress," port 81.
- Docker takes that request on 81 and passes it into the container on port 80.
- The Apache server that wordpress likes handles the request.

What **actually** happens:

- Nginx gets the request on port 433, gets the right IP address, and reports 502 bad gateway.  The wordpress container never gets the request; nginx is not, apparently, passing anything through.

> connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.y.z.a, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.31.0.4:81/", host: "mysite.com:433"

I feel like this is a simple enough thing that my mistake should be obvious.  I've looked through all of the other similar questions here, and think that I've incorporated what's necessary.  Obviously I'm missing something, though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, if anyone else is ever in the same spot:

- I moved everything on the wordpress container over to 81.  So in docker-compose.yml, instead of being 81:80, it's just 81:81.
- Then I noticed that I still couldn't even "curl -v http://wordpress:81" from another container.  My "WTF" flag went up.
- It turns out that, with Apache, you can't just define a VirtualHost that listens to a particular port.  You **also** have to add the port to /etc/apache2/ports.conf with a "Listen 81" directive.

That's a week of my life spent learning that particular lesson.  Hope it's helpful to someone out there.